# 'view' is undefined in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

This is probably an easy fix but I've been struggling trying to get the 'view' and 'product' prop defined, both the 'product' (which should be an Object with the data) and 'view' props are being returned as undefined, but in the Events tab for Vue in Chrome, I can see that the data is being passed in via payload as an Object which all the correct data.

So I have a table that's populated with data, each row with an ID, once selected should take you to the edit page which you can see below, the data is being pulled but is not populating the form and was wondering whereabouts I am going wrong with this?

This is the form:

```
<template>
<div class="main-section">
<div class="details-form">
    <div class="details-form">
        <div>
            <label>Details:</label>
        </div>

        <div id="productPriority">
            <label for="productPriority">Priority: </label>
            <input id="productPriority" v-model="order" type="number" title="Product Priority" name="productPriority" placeholder="Please enter the product priority" required>
        </div>

        </div>
</div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import {event} from '@/services';
import {http} from '@/services';
import {productStore} from '@/stores';

export default {
    name: "ProductDetails",

    props:['product', 'view'],

    data(){
        return{
            order:'',
            description:'',
            url: '',
            image_id: '',
        }
    },


    watch:{

        view() {
            if(this.view === 'product-details') {
                this.order = this.product[0].attributes.order;
                this.description = this.product[0].attributes.description;
                this.url = this.product[0].attributes.url;
                this.image_id = this.product[0].attributes.image_id;
            }
        },


        product: {
            hander: function() {

             if((this.product.length > 1) &&( this.product.attributes === "product")) {
                this.order = this.product.attributes.order;
                this.description = this.product.attributes.description;
                this.url = this.product.attributes.url;
                this.image_id = this.product.attributes.image_id;
            }

        }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Example of the data I am trying to pass:

```
"type": "product",
  "id": "1",
  "attributes": {
    "image_id": 1,
    "order": 1,
    "description": "abc",
    "url": "http://testingurl1.com"
```

The View page that the section is loaded from:

```
<product-badge-details v-show="subview === 'product-badge-details'" :product="product"/>

<script>
import {productStore} from '@/stores';
'@/components/products/ProductBadge';

export default {
    components: {ProductDetails},

    props:['subview', 'product'],

    data() {
        return {
            state: productStore.state,

        }
    },
}
</script>
```

Comment: Can we see an example of the data you're passing in to your component properties?

Comment: @AlexMulchinock I have added an example to the question!

Comment: Which property are you passing this data into? Can you show data for both properties?

Comment: @AlexMulchinock This is what I am passing the data to, from another view which has all of the data, this has the separate data for each ID, I've cut the form down to minimise the code for the question

Comment: My apologies, I don't think I was clear enough in my last question. I'm trying to understand which property you pass this data into - is it "product", "view" or both? :)

Comment: @AlexMulchinock Ah my bad, no worries! And it's both, but currently the props are returning as undefined

Comment: Not a problem. I really want to help you with this - but there is some key information missing from your question (like the fact that both props are returning as undefined). Rather than me clutter up the comments with additional questions, can you read back through your question - and be absolutely sure you have provided all relevant information. A few things aren't adding up (for example, is "product" a string, an object or an array?). Also, include console errors if you are seeing any.

Comment: @AlexMulchinock I've updated the question further with more information that may be useful and I'm currently receiving no console errors